# Using compareAndSet for Thread safety

Tags: java, multithreading

How is the following demo code thread-safe? We are ensuring whether the value is not modified in CAS instruction and then doing an increment on int. Doesn't `return v + 1;` step beat the whole purpose as it can skip updates of threads.

Here atomic integer is used to mimic a non blocking int counter.

```
//Here value is an atomic integer
public int increment() 
{
   int v;
   for(;;) 
   {
      v = value.get();
      if(value.compareAndSet(v, v + 1))
         return v + 1;   
   }
}
```

Shouldn't the code be like this:

```
public int increment() 
{
   int v;
   for(;;) 
   {
      v = value.get();
      if(value.compareAndSet(v, v + 1))
         return value.get();   
   }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`compareAndSet()` returns `true` if the current value equals the expected value `v`, and thus the value was updated to `v + 1`.

In your first version, if both threads get the *same* initial value then one will succeed (updating to `v + 1`) and the other will fail (since the current value is no longer `v`) and retry using `v + 1` and `v + 2`.

If this code is intended to return unique keys then the first version is correct, since at the point `compareAndSet()` returned `true` the current value is guaranteed to be `v + 1` (even if only briefly). The second version may return duplicate values due to a race condition if another thread modifies the value in between your calls to `compareAndSet()` and `get()`.

That said, you might want to investigate `AtomicInteger`'s `incrementAndGet()` method, which does pretty much the same thing but more efficiently (no explicit looping).

Answer (score 2):

Define "work".

Let's say `value` is initially zero. If the first function is called 100 times it would return each number between 1 and 100 exactly once. The second function doesn't have this property.

Both functions can produce values that are out of date by the time the function returns.

Which is more "correct" really depends on the expected semantics of `increment`.